# smtp and pop3 how to work with localhost

Tags: java, smtp, localhost, ubuntu-12.04, pop3

I am new with smtp and pop3. 
I want to create a client application that sends and received emails using pop3 and smtp. 
I need a localhost domain and I don't know how to set this.

I am working on Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: probably you want to send email using a JAVA program and want to read mails from inbox. Have i got your question right?

Comment: yes you are right! I don't know how to set a localhost in order to start working a little bit on using these protocols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/) is an example of how to send mail using SMTP in java and [here](http://metoojava.wordpress.com/2010/03/21/java-code-to-receive-mail-using-javamailapi/) is the example of how to read mails using java.

Comment: Thank you very much. Should I download and install hMailServer on localhost in order to do some tests?WHat do u suggest?

Comment: you don't need your own server for the tasks that you mentioned above.